# Difference of pixel value between MATLAB and OpenCV extracting frames from video

Tags: matlab, opencv, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I'm trying to open a video file encoded with H264 using Matlab. I rip the first frame, analyze the north-western square 9x9, I get the following matrix:

```
   116   128   126   126   127   126   127   126   130

   125   128   127   131   131   130   131   129   127

   147   150   150   152   157   151   157   152   149

   145   152   158   151   155   158   154   158   156

   145   155   157   155   154   161   152   158   154

   149   154   151   156   158   152   157   152   156

   151   152   155   152   158   151   155   150   151

   148   161   156   157   155   155   152   152   154

   150   157   150   152   151   149   151   156   155
```

I try to do the same thing with OpenCV and have the following result:

```
   116   128   125   125   126   125   126   125   130 

   124   128   126   131   131   130   131   129   126 

   146   150   150   152   157   151   157   152   149 

   145   152   158   151   154   158   153   158   156 

   145   154   157   154   153   160   152   158   153 

   149   153   151   156   158   152   157   152   156 

   151   152   154   152   158   151   154   150   151 

   147   160   156   157   154   154   152   152   153 

   150   157   150   152   151   149   151   156   154
```

It is seen that approximately in 50 percent of cases the brightness value of the pixel in the first matrix is one more than in the second one. For this reason, the results of further processing, respectively, in Matlab and OpenCV are different. Can someone explain to me, what is this effect related to and how to overcome it?

Comment: Could be a difference in the video decoder, OpenCV uses ffmpeg I think, don't know for Matlab. If you use in Matlab `rgb2gray()` and `cvtColor()` in OpenCV, I think the formula is slightly different.

Comment: If the video is not raw (very likely) then its compressed, and the compression/decompresion codecs may be different between systems. Not even the widely used jpg has a defined decompression matrix. Basically, wither you write your own code that does the same thing for both, or deal with the fact that they will not be equal.

Comment: Catree, I get the matrix before doing any transformations such as cvtColor() and rgb2gray(). The matrix I printed above is from the blue channel. Anyway, on the video being examined, the red, green and blue channels are equal.

Comment: Then, the most plausible reason for me is the `H264` video decoding step. To solve the issue, find a way to use the same video decoder or use an uncompressed video file (easiest solution for me is to extract the video frames on disk in png format for example).